# doesn't GridView or Grid have Click Event in C# UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

doesn't GridView or Grid have Click Event in C# UWP?

i know it has 'RightTapped'.. but i couldn't find 'Click' Event.

for example,

`Click="OnElementClicked"`

```
 <GridView>
    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="ElementFrame0" Width="470"
               Height="450" CanDrag="True" AllowDrop="True" Click="OnElementClicked"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="ElementFrame1" Width="470" 
               Height="450" CanDrag="True" AllowDrop="True" Click="OnElementClicked"/>
    </Grid>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Grid` and `GridView` (like all `UIElemets`) has the `Tapped` event

You can also use the `ItemClick` on the `GridView` if `SelectionMode = None` and `IsItemClickEnabled = true`

Comment: Thank you for answering!